# Sql Function Issue "The last statement included within a function must be a return statement"

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below SQL function I have to return value based on condition but it throws a error.

> "The last statement included within a function must be a return
>   statement."

Pls help me to overcome this issue.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBatchReleaseQuantity]   
(
@i_LocationID VARCHAR(50),
    @i_ProductID INT,
    @i_StartDate VARCHAR(50),  
    @i_EndDate VARCHAR(50),  
    @i_ProductInFlow int
)  
RETURNS numeric(18,3)  
 --WITH ENCRYPTION     
AS  
BEGIN  

  IF (@i_ProductInFlow ='2')
  BEGIN

  RETURN (SElECT ISNULL( SUM( BatchReleaseQuantity),0.00)  From  BatchReleaseDetails BRD
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR ON BR.BatchReleaseID=BRD.BatchReleaseID
  Where  ProductId=@i_ProductID  AND LocationID=@i_LocationID AND BRD.CreatedOn>=convert(datetime,@i_StartDate+' 00:00:00') AND BRD.CreatedOn<=convert(datetime,@i_EndDate+' 23:59:59'))
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
  RETURN(SElECT ISNULL( SUM( AcceptedQuantity),0.00)  From  GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND
  LEFT OUTER JOIN GoodsReceivedNote GRN ON GRN.LocationID=@i_LocationID
  Where  ProductId=@i_ProductID  AND GRN.LocationID=@i_LocationID AND GRND.CreatedOn>=convert(datetime,@i_StartDate+' 00:00:00') AND GRND.CreatedOn<=convert(datetime,@i_EndDate+' 23:59:59'))
  END 
END
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error? The last statement in your function is an `IF` statement, not a `RETURN` statement. You can trivially refactor that by storing the result in a variable, and then returning that variable after the `IF`.

Comment: Your value should be returned immediately before last `END`.

Answer (score 18):

As the error suggests, the last statement must be a return statement. Unlike some other languages the flow of the `IF/ELSE` statement is not checked during compilation, so SQL Server is not aware that one of the branches is mandatory (even `ELSE`). Since this is not checked there is no way of knowing whether the function will return a value unless the last statement is a return statement. Even a simple function like this will fail:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FlowTest()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0;
    END
END
```

The solution is to just remove the `ELSE`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FlowTest()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END
    -- ELSE REMOVED
    RETURN 0;

END
```

The function will stop execution when if reaches the first `RETURN`, so the `ELSE` is not required anyway.

So your function would become:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBatchReleaseQuantity]   
(
@i_LocationID VARCHAR(50),
    @i_ProductID INT,
    @i_StartDate VARCHAR(50),  
    @i_EndDate VARCHAR(50),  
    @i_ProductInFlow int
)  
RETURNS numeric(18,3)  
 --WITH ENCRYPTION     
AS  
BEGIN  

  IF (@i_ProductInFlow ='2')
  BEGIN

    RETURN (SElECT  ISNULL( SUM( BatchReleaseQuantity),0.00)  
            FROM    BatchReleaseDetails BRD
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR 
                        ON BR.BatchReleaseID=BRD.BatchReleaseID
            WHERE   ProductId = @i_ProductID  
            AND     LocationID = @i_LocationID 
            AND     BRD.CreatedOn >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @i_StartDate+' 00:00:00') 
            AND     BRD.CreatedOn <= CONVERT(DATETIME,@i_EndDate + ' 23:59:59')
        )
  END

  RETURN (  SELECT  ISNULL( SUM( AcceptedQuantity),0.00)  
            FROM    GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN GoodsReceivedNote GRN 
                        ON GRN.LocationID=@i_LocationID
            WHERE   ProductId = @i_ProductID  
            AND     GRN.LocationID = @i_LocationID 
            AND     GRND.CreatedOn >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @i_StartDate+' 00:00:00') 
            AND     GRND.CreatedOn <= CONVERT(DATETIME, @i_EndDate+' 23:59:59')
        )
  END 

END
```

I can't see how the function will perform well though, and why you are passing a date as a varchar is beyond me. Do you not care about things that were created between 23:59:59 and midnight?

I would be inclined to refactor this as an inline tablevalued function, and use dates properly, e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBatchReleaseQuantityTVP]   
(
    @i_LocationID VARCHAR(50),
    @i_ProductID INT,
    @i_StartDate DATE,  
    @i_EndDate DATE,  
    @i_ProductInFlow int
)  
RETURNS TABLE
 --WITH ENCRYPTION     
AS  
RETURN 
(   SElECT  ReturnValue = ISNULL( SUM( BatchReleaseQuantity),0.00)  
    FROM    BatchReleaseDetails BRD
            LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR 
                ON BR.BatchReleaseID=BRD.BatchReleaseID
    WHERE   ProductId = @i_ProductID  
    AND     LocationID = @i_LocationID 
    AND     BRD.CreatedOn >= @i_StartDate
    AND     BRD.CreatedOn < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @i_EndDate)
    AND     @i_ProductInFlow ='2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ISNULL(SUM( AcceptedQuantity),0.00)  
    FROM    GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND
            LEFT OUTER JOIN GoodsReceivedNote GRN 
                ON GRN.LocationID=@i_LocationID
    WHERE   ProductId = @i_ProductID  
    AND     GRN.LocationID = @i_LocationID 
    AND     GRND.CreatedOn >= @i_StartDate
    AND     GRND.CreatedOn < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @i_EndDate)
    AND     ISNULL(@i_ProductInFlow, '') != '2'
);
```

Then whenever you would call `dbo.GetBatchReleaseQuantity(...)` simply call `(SELECT ReturnValue FROM dbo.GetBatchReleaseQuantityTVP(...))`. This will perform significantly better, and will also avoid people passing invalid dates to a varchar parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Function expect a return at the last line.
Just modify your function by assigning the result to variable @nReturn and return it in last line.

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBatchReleaseQuantity]   
(
@i_LocationID VARCHAR(50),
    @i_ProductID INT,
    @i_StartDate VARCHAR(50),  
    @i_EndDate VARCHAR(50),  
    @i_ProductInFlow int
)  
RETURNS numeric(18,3)  
 --WITH ENCRYPTION     
AS  
BEGIN  

 DECLARE @nReturn numeric(18,3)

  IF (@i_ProductInFlow ='2')
  BEGIN

  SElECT @nReturn = ISNULL( SUM( BatchReleaseQuantity),0.00)  From  BatchReleaseDetails BRD
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR ON BR.BatchReleaseID=BRD.BatchReleaseID
  Where  ProductId=@i_ProductID  AND LocationID=@i_LocationID AND BRD.CreatedOn>=convert(datetime,@i_StartDate+' 00:00:00') AND BRD.CreatedOn<=convert(datetime,@i_EndDate+' 23:59:59')
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
  SElECT @nReturn = ISNULL( SUM( AcceptedQuantity),0.00)  From  GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND
  LEFT OUTER JOIN GoodsReceivedNote GRN ON GRN.LocationID=@i_LocationID
  Where  ProductId=@i_ProductID  AND GRN.LocationID=@i_LocationID AND GRND.CreatedOn>=convert(datetime,@i_StartDate+' 00:00:00') AND GRND.CreatedOn<=convert(datetime,@i_EndDate+' 23:59:59')
  END 

  RETURN  @nReturn
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return from an SQL function like the way you do in C++ or C#. There should be just one return statement at the end of the `FUNCTION` block:

So just put the return values inside a local variable and use a `RETURN` statement at the end of your function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBatchReleaseQuantity]   
(
@i_LocationID VARCHAR(50),
    @i_ProductID INT,
    @i_StartDate VARCHAR(50),  
    @i_EndDate VARCHAR(50),  
    @i_ProductInFlow int
)  
RETURNS numeric(18,3)  
 --WITH ENCRYPTION     
AS  
BEGIN  


  DECLARE @retval NUMERIC(18, 3)    
  IF (@i_ProductInFlow ='2')
  BEGIN

  SElECT @retval = ISNULL( SUM( BatchReleaseQuantity),0.00)  From  BatchReleaseDetails BRD
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR ON BR.BatchReleaseID=BRD.BatchReleaseID
  Where  ProductId=@i_ProductID  AND LocationID=@i_LocationID AND BRD.CreatedOn>=convert(datetime,@i_StartDate+' 00:00:00') AND BRD.CreatedOn<=convert(datetime,@i_EndDate+' 23:59:59')
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
  SElECT @retval =  ISNULL( SUM( AcceptedQuantity),0.00)  From  GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND
  LEFT OUTER JOIN GoodsReceivedNote GRN ON GRN.LocationID=@i_LocationID
  Where  ProductId=@i_ProductID  AND GRN.LocationID=@i_LocationID AND GRND.CreatedOn>=convert(datetime,@i_StartDate+' 00:00:00') AND GRND.CreatedOn<=convert(datetime,@i_EndDate+' 23:59:59')
  END 

  RETURN @retval
END
```